# Flutter run renders white screen | app does not load

Tags: flutter

Whenever I run `flutter run` the app loads, no errors in the console, but the screen just renders white. There is an image below depicting this.

I have tried running `flutter doctor` and restarting the app on numerous occasions but to no luck, and everything seems normal.

Here is a portion of my `main.dart` file which is the only real relevant portion that would be required.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'pages/Onboarding1.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'theme/routes.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(App1());
}

class App1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'HomePage',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Color(0xff33333D),
        secondaryHeaderColor: Color(0xff33333D),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Color(0xff33333D),
        ),
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      routes: AppRoutes.define(),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: `Home` is a different page

I have no idea why the app is not rendering. I have tried the fixes everyone has suggested in similar threads, but nothing has worked.

App Routes:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:App1/pages/Home.dart';
import 'package:App1/pages/Login.dart';
import 'package:App1/pages/SignUp.dart';

class AppRoutes {
  AppRoutes._();

  static const String authLogin = '/auth-login';
  static const String authSignUp = '/auth-signup';
  static const String home = '/home';

  static Map<String, WidgetBuilder> define() {
    return {
      authLogin: (context) => Login(),
      authSignUp: (context) => SignUp(),
      home: (context) => Home(),
    };
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: show what do your `AppRoutes.define()`

Comment: @sajithlakmal added to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a problem of your `await Firebase.initializeApp();` where it never return a value. try remove it and it should work

Comment: This is legit the only answer out of at least 5 i've seen that works. Thanks Lakmal!